# Why I am getting these Typescript compile time errors?

Tags: .net, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I dont have any idea why these errors are appearing, while I copied the whole ClientApp folder from running application where these are not there.

[image]

My structure of project is ;

[image]

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "crossvertise-calander-system",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "saturn-datepicker": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "md-date-range-picker": "^0.8.3",
    "ng2-daterange-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-mat-daterange-picker": "0.0.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/moment": "3.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.27",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Can any body help me how to get rid of these errors. I dont know how to avoid these errors. These are really slowing down my development

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

- Delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file if it exists
- Run `npm install` command

If this, still doesn't fix your problem, then in your `spec.ts` file, add the below import:

```
import {} from 'jasmine';
```

Comment: I dont know this didnt solve my problem. I tried to copy one by one every file and folder where it is perfectly running and compiling. Sudenly this starting to appear . I have no idea why. Even I am not touching front end ClientApp folder at all and everything doing in backend code, it starting to appear. Have no idea why typescript compiler start behaving weirdly

Comment: @Usman Check your imports. When you copied angular project to some other location. The directory structure may have changed.